# Checkbox for images in an ASP.NET repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with ASP.NET. I am using a repeater to display images, and I also am using a check box for each image.

How can I select individual images and update their values as per image id?

My code is:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <img ID="ImageZoom" runat="server" 
                src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> '
                style="display: inline; height:auto; left: 0pt; top: 0pt;
                width:auto;" />
           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "select individual image and update their value as per image id"?

Comment: I am saving a vaue for each image such as image name . if i select that image image , i am giving an option to change image text value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox for images in an ASP.NET repeater controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068545/checkbox-for-images-in-an-asp-net-repeater-controls)

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to implement this, something like this should do the trick:

**Without jQuery**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <img ID="ImageZoom" runat="server"
                onclick="imageClickHandler(this,event);" 
                src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> '
                style="display: inline; height:auto; left: 0pt; top: 0pt;
                width:auto;" />
           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

function imageClickHandler(s,e){
//do something with the current image that is being clicked on.
//The parameter 's' is a reference to the caller of this method and the 'e' contains
//event data  
}
```

**With jQuery**

If your using jQuery, you could also try something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <img ID="ImageZoom" runat="server"
                class="handled" 
                src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> '
                style="display: inline; height:auto; left: 0pt; top: 0pt;
                width:auto;" />
           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.3"></script>
$(function(){
  $("img.handled").click(function(){
    //alerts the id of the image thats being clicked on.
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Rob ANgelier : I want Image id of repeater in c# code on select of check box . how can i get this . I am using a button to upadate

Comment: You should take a look at the following information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx